# graphql - combining results from multiple queries into one array

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am using graphQL to perform a search across multiple mongoDB collections and API's by combining queries. All queries return a result type of

```
{
  _id: string; 
  name: string; 
  type: string;
}
```

Is there any way to flatten the data into a single array?

**Combined query example:**

```
query searchAll {
    books(input: {text: "e"}) {
        _id
        name
        type
    }
    magazines(input: {text: "e"}) {
        _id
        name
        type
    }
}
```

**Response currently looks like:**

```
{"data": {
        "books": [
            {
                "_id": "5a8ac759c25b7235ffdc6888",
                "name": "someBook",
                "type": "book"
            }
        ],
        "magazines": [
            {
                "_id": "5a87005bc25b7235ffdc4bdf",
                "name": "someMagazine-1",
                "type": "magazine"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a870067c25b7235ffdc4be4",
                "name": "someMagazine-2",
                "type": "client"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Desired response:**

```
{"data": {
    "results": [
            {
                "_id": "5a8ac759c25b7235ffdc6888",
                "name": "someBook",
                "type": "book"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a87005bc25b7235ffdc4bdf",
                "name": "someMagazine-1",
                "type": "magazine"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a870067c25b7235ffdc4be4",
                "name": "someMagazine-2",
                "type": "client"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to look into using interfaces, here's an example of a (slightly richer) schema definition:

```
interface Searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Book implements Searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  author: Author!
  publisher: Publisher!
  isbn: String!
}

type Magazine implements Searchable {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  publisher: Publisher!
  issn: String!
}

input SearchInput {
  text: String!
}

type Query {
  search(input: SearchInput!): [Searchable!]!
}
```

Here's how you'd query it:

```
query searchAll {
  search(input: {text: "e"}) {
    __typename
    id
    name
    ... on Book {
      author
      isbn
    }
    ... on Magazine {
      issn
    }
  }
}
```

The resolver for `search` would be responsible for calling all the different collections and aggregating the results into a single array. Going into more depth than this is implementation-specific, but there should be docs for using interfaces (and unions, which are similar) in whichever GraphQL implementation you're using.

The `__typename` field is what tells you the concrete type of the returned object, thereby letting front-end code do the appropriate display logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked into interfaces, and based on your suggestion, I have a few questions:

1. What if book and magazine are always type `Searchable`, but come from different databases (there is never a need to add additional unique fields)?


2. How does the search resolver look? (compared to the individual `Books` and `Magazines` resolvers)

Comment: I see. I guess I was thinking about graphQL wrong (just started using it). I thought the point was to NOT create a long API aggregator, but to instead write different queries + resolvers and flexibly use them as needed. In my example above, I was thinking I could write 4 different queries + resolvers to search across 4 databases, and then be able to query all or just a subset of them as needed. As opposed to writing one long resolver that fetches from all 4 databases.

Comment: What would be the main benefit of aggregating the results into one resolver, v.s. running individual queries with corresponding resolvers?

Thanks again!

Comment: Ultimately the reason to choose between the two approaches (one search field vs multiple) is going to come down to what client-side behaviour you want.  If your end result is essentially going to be a single paginated list, a single field (using interfaces) is preferred. But this will make the pagination logic complex, because you need to coordinate it across data sources, which usually means fetching a full page per source and throwing away the overflow.

Comment: If you don't need this single megasearch search behaviour, what you had originally is probably a better starting point. This is definitely the kind of decision that comes from product needs rather than one approach being technically superior.